# Connect pgsql using PHP over web api don't work

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a web api script from pos system that works retriving data using a form and submit.

"select sum (antal*pris) from batch_salg where fakturadate = '2023-08-25' "

`fetch_from_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$select,$from,$where,$order_by,$limit);`

```
$serverurl="https://somedomain/pos/api";
$saldiuser = 'apiuser';
$db='posdb_9945864';
$api_key='dsdkfswaewmfmkev4546';
```

I have limited skils in  an they are in Mysql, Im trying to get something like this to work

```
pg_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(pg_error()); 
pg_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(pg_error()); 

$sho1_pg = pg_query("SELECT sum (antal*pris)  FROM batch_salg WHERE fakturadate ='$date_today'")
or die(pg_error());  
$shop1_row = pg_fetch_array($sho1_pg);
$shop1_today = $shop1_row['sum'];
```

First part works and output total sum by items sold * price
Second do not connect to db. strugling to get it to connect using the url and api key
Getting this:

> Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: invalid port number: "pos_99" in /var/www/genogbrug.dk/stuff/jk1.php on line 24
> Connection attempt failed.

Update
Have added the code that worked, but no port number is defined in that?
The second part was an atempt to connect using the paranerters i had and old myql.

```html
<html>
 <body>

<?php

  
   
(isset($_GET['action']))?$action=$_GET['action']:$action=NULL;

(isset($_POST['select']))?$select=$_POST['select']:$select=NULL;
(isset($_POST['from']))?$from=$_POST['from']:$from=NULL;
(isset($_POST['where']))?$where=$_POST['where']:$where=NULL;
(isset($_POST['order_by']))?$order_by=$_POST['order_by']:$order_by=NULL;
(isset($_POST['limit']))?$limit=$_POST['limit']:$limit=NULL;
(isset($_POST['update']))?$update=$_POST['update']:$update=NULL;
(isset($_POST['set']))?$set=$_POST['set']:$set=NULL;
(isset($_POST['insert']))?$insert=$_POST['insert']:$insert=NULL;
(isset($_POST['fields']))?$fields=$_POST['fields']:$fields=NULL;
(isset($_POST['values']))?$values=$_POST['values']:$values=NULL;

if (isset($_GET['select'])) $select=$_GET['select'];
if (isset($_GET['from'])) $from=$_GET['from'];
if (isset($_GET['where'])) $where=$_GET['where'];
if (isset($_GET['order_by'])) $order_by=$_GET['order_by'];
if (isset($_GET['update'])) $update=$_GET['update'];
if (isset($_GET['set'])) $set=$_GET['set'];
if (isset($_GET['insert'])) $insert=$_GET['insert'];
if (isset($_GET['fields'])) $fields=$_GET['fields'];
if (isset($_GET['values'])) $values=$_GET['values'];

$serverurl="https://somedomain.com/pos/api";
$saldiuser = 'apiuser';
$db='DBname';
$api_key='125155dfgtr5trg5t1tr5t';

if ($action) {
    if ($action == 'fetch_from_table') fetch_from_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$select,$from,$where,$order_by,$limit);
    elseif ($action == 'update_table') update_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$update,$set,$where);
    elseif ($action == 'insert_into_table') insert_into_table($serverurl,$saldiuser,$db,$api_key,$insert,$fields,$values);
} else {
  print "<form name=\"rest_api_client\" action=\"rest_api_client.php?action=fetch_from_table\" method='post'>\n";
    print "<table><tbody>";
  print "<tr><td>Select</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='select' value=\"$select\"></td></tr>\n";
    print "<tr><td>From</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='from' value=\"$from\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td>Where</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='where' value=\"$where\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td>Order by</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='order_by' value=\"$order_by\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td>Limit</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='limit' value=\"$limit\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='go' value='Go'></td></tr>\n";
    print "</tbody></table>";
    print "</form>";
  print "<form name=\"rest_api_client\" action=\"rest_api_client.php?action=update_table\" method='post'>\n";
    print "<table><tbody>";
  print "<tr><td>Update</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='update' value=\"$update\"></td></tr>\n";
    print "<tr><td>Set</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='set' value=\"$set\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td>Where</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='where' value=\"$where\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='go' value='Go'></td></tr>\n";
    print "</tbody></table>";
    print "</form>";
    print "<form name=\"rest_api_client\" action=\"rest_api_client.php?action=insert_into_table\" method='post'>\n";
    print "<table><tbody>";
  print "<tr><td>Insert into</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='insert' value=\"$insert\"></td></tr>\n";
    print "<tr><td>Fields</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='fields' value=\"$fields\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td>Values</td><td><input style=\"width:1000px;\" type='text' name='values' value=\"$values\"></td></tr>";
    print "<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='go' value='Go'></td></tr>\n";
    print "</tbody></table>";
    print "</form>";

}
function fetch_from_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$select,$from,$where,$order_by,$limit) {
  $result = file_get_contents($serverurl."/rest_api.php?action=fetch_from_table&saldiuser=$saldiuser&db=$db&key=$api_key&select=".urlencode($select)."&from=".urlencode($from)."&where=".urlencode($where)."&order_by=".urlencode($order_by)."&limit=".urlencode($limit));
  $result = json_decode($result, true);
    if (!is_array($result)) {
        print "error: ".$result;
    } else {
        print "<table border='1'><tbody>";
        $rows=count($result);
        $cols=count($result[0]);
        for ($x=0;$x<$rows;$x++){
            print  "<tr>";
            for ($y=0;$y<$cols;$y++) {
                print "<td>".$result[$x][$y]."</td>";
            }
            print  "</tr>";
        }
        print "</tbody></table>";
    }
    print "<a href=\"rest_api_client.php?select=$select&from=$from&where=$where&order_by=$order_by&limit=$limit\">Return to query page</a>";
}
function update_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$update,$set,$where) {
  $result = file_get_contents($serverurl."/rest_api.php?action=update_table&db=$db&saldiuser=$saldiuser&key=$api_key&update=".urlencode($update)."&set=".urlencode($set)."&where=".urlencode($where));
  $result = json_decode($result, true);
    if (!is_numeric($result)) {
        print "error: ".$result;
    } else {
        print "<table border='1'><tbody>";
        print "<td>".$result."</td>";
        print  "</tr>";
        print "</tbody></table>";
    }
    print "<br><a href=\"rest_api_client.php?update=$update&set=$set&where=$where\">Return to query page</a>";
}
function insert_into_table($serverurl,$db,$saldiuser,$api_key,$insert,$fields,$values) {
  $result = file_get_contents($serverurl."/rest_api.php?action=insert_into_table&saldiuser=$saldiuser&db=$db&key=$api_key&insert=".urlencode($insert)."&fields=".urlencode($fields)."&values=".urlencode($values));
  $result = json_decode($result, true);
    if (!is_numeric($result)) {
        print "error: ".$result;
    } else {
        print "<table border='1'><tbody>";
        print "<td>".$result."</td>";
        print  "</tr>";
        print "</tbody></table>";
    }
    print "<br><a href=\"rest_api_client.php?insert=$insert&fields=$fields&values=$values\">Return to query page</a>";
}

?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A port number must be an actual number, not a string. But its unclear where in your code you have actually set that value. Try to provide a [mre] of the issue

Comment: Unrelated to question but https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php would be better to use than `pg_query`. Can use parameterized queries there, and safely pass in all data. `SELECT sum (antal*pris)  FROM batch_salg WHERE fakturadate = ?`

Comment: `Have added the code that worked, but no port number is defined`...OK, but so what? That code is making a http request to another API, not a direct database connection. They are not equivalent or comparable. It's completely irrelevant to your current issue. Read the answer below, and the documentation page, to understand how to structure your pg_connect code properly

Comment: Ok, sorry if I made my question confysing or wrong.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I made my question confysing or wrong. I only have the given info to retrive data url, user ,database, and api key. I would like to be able to retrive the sum(antal*pris) from that only and use it to display when needed. I tourgt I could use the "old" i had and modify it. Basicly im lokking to get the "sum" from the pgsql an be able to post it on the page when it loads with no forms or submit. But was strugling with that. Again sorry for any confusion from my part. will read in to it and see if it make any sens to me

Comment: `I would like to be able to retrive the sum(antal*pris) from that only and use it to display`...but it seems like you already have the code to do that, and it works. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes and No
I can retrieve the sum by the function executed by the form in the code that worked provided by the pos system owner.
I was planning to use it another way so that I could call it by an “echo $ sum_now” on the page. And that was updated when the page was loaded or refreshed. 
Therefor the code that I tried to alter, that didn’t work. Sorry if that just made It confusing.
The code I have is calling table and data by a function. I was looking to do a query or something like it having the result as”$sum_now = $sum_row[sum]; or something like it

Comment: OK. You don't need to remove the API code to do that though, you would just need to use the result a different way, I think. And anyway it doesn't sound like you have the direct access to the database, so pg_connect is not useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation for [`pg_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php):

> The old syntax with multiple parameters $conn = pg_connect("host",
> "port", "options", "tty", "dbname") has been deprecated.

You should use the syntax with the connection string, e.g.:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=<your-host> user=<your-user> password=<your-password>");
```

Additionally, your current code doesn't match the old syntax: the second parameter is supposed to be the port and you are passing the user name instead. The third parameter is wrong too.

Comment: Deprecation doesn't mean it would actually stop working though- not yet anyway. Unless the manual has used that term incorrectly, of course

Comment: @ADyson Note that the second parameter is "port" while the OP passed `DB_USER`, hence the error.

Comment: That should probably be in your answer then :-)

Comment: @ADyson You're right, I added it to the answer.